# how to pass values from extensions to AGI script and use that values in script

Tags: php, asterisk, agi, phpagi

extension to call php_agi

```
exten => 8380,n,AGI(php_falup.agi,${MSISDN},${var})
```

php_agiscript to grep values

```
<?
//require 'phpagi.php';
require('include/phpagi-2.20/phpagi.php');
$agi = new AGI();
$Variable =$agi->request[agi_arg_1,agi_arg_2];
```

I am trying this isthis currect.

Comment: What is actually happening and what do you expect to happen? How are they different?

Comment: thanku i want to passvalue from asterisk extension and use that value in the agi program,for kepting below answered values its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can access passed vars by

```
$var1=$argv[1];
$var2=$argv[2];
```